# Restore Vertical Scroll missing on form after switch to Universal Theme

Tags: scroll, apex

I'm using Oracle 18.c and Apex 19.1.  I recently switched an existing application to Universal Theme.  I noticed that the vertical scrolls were missing from interactive reports and from forms.  I was able to restore the vertical and horizontal scrolls to the Interactive Report by going to **Attributes / Heading**.  I set the **Fixed To** = **Region** and set the **Maximum Report Height** to **680**.  That seems to have fixed the problem with Interactive Reports.
However I still have a problem with Forms.  In Apex I click on the form name, and note that the **Appearance / Template** is set to **Standard** and the **Appearance / Template Options** is set to **Use Template Defaults, Scroll - Default**.  I can't figure out how to enable the vertical scroll so that users can edit fields on the lower part of the form.
I should add that there is indeed a scroll bar on the form. The scroll bar itself slides up and down, but the body of the screen remains still.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I eventually solved the problem.  I built this page from the Interactive Report / Form wizard.  On the region, the **Layout / Position** defaulted to **Breadcrumb Bar**.  When I changed the **Layout / Position** to **Body**, the scroll bar behaved as expected.